# Getting error 0x8007042C when updating Outlook Offline Adress Book

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010

My Outlook Offline Address Book hasn't been updated in a few weeks/months. I noticed it when my new coworkers didn't show up in my contacts. They show up properly if I select the **All Users** address book. So I tried to manually update the address book and got the following error:

> Task '[my email]' reported error (0x8007042C) : 'Unknown Error 0x8007042C'

I tried renaming my Outlook file and creating a new profile but the problem remained. Upon my profile's creation, I do get the last version of the OAB, but then updates will fail. I tried repairing the Outlook Installation, but that too didn't work.

Logging on a different PC using the same account will be fine and I can update the OAB. If a user logs in my faulty PC, he will also get the problem, so it might be related to the installation.

Looking in the Event Viewer I see :

> The Background Intelligent Transfer Service service depends on the COM+ Event System service which failed to start because of the following error:
>
> The specified module could not be found.

Except from that OAB problem, my emails are working perfectly fine, I can send and receive emails and book meetings with coworkers and use the rooms specified on the server.

What can be the cause of this problem? What solutions do I have short of re-imaging my machine?

Comment: According to Microsoft, it's to do with Proxy. . . https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/939765

Comment: Have you tried using Office's Repair features yet? If you Ctrl-Right-click the outlook icon *in the system tray*, choose "Test E-mail AutoConfiguration", and then run the test, does it complete and show the correct server information?

Comment: That Microsoft link is for a different error (0x8004010F) for a different version (2003 and 2007, I have 2010). Proxy settings are global to the workplace.

Comment: AutoConfiguration doesn't show an error, but it ends with "Auth Package: Unspecified", I'm not sure if that's what it's supposed to do.

Comment: I forgot to mention that ALL other email functions are working properly, I can send and receive emails with no errors.

Comment: We reinstalled Office completely, tried installing 2010 Pro, 2007 Pro and both version have the same problem.